# Django url pattern to ignore extra characters

Tags: django, django-urls

I have a django url shown below :

```
url(r'^update_status/field1/(?P<field1_id>.*)/field2/(?P<field2_id>.*)/$', 'update_status', name='update_status')
```

This catches both the urls like :

```
update_status/field1/0445df4d8e1c43ae9/field2/f12b6b5c98/mraid.js/
```

and

```
update_status/field1/0445df4d8e1c43ae9/field2/f12b6b5c98
```

I  want to capture only the second url . What should be changed in the django url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression `(?P<field_id>.*)` catches any character, including `/` characters. You want to restrict it to the format of the `field_id`s like this: `(?P<field1_id>[0-9a-f]+)` (same for field2_id).

Note: I'm assuming your id consists only of hexadecimal characters.

Comment: (?P<field1_id>[0-9a-f]+) should do a better job. [0-5] for hexadecimals.

Comment: yep, `+` makes sure no empty ids. I edited my response. But I don't understand your [0-5] comment.

Comment: That was a mistake. `[0-9a-f]+` works for hexadecimals.

Comment: How to ignore just the / character ,that is it should ignore any call which has / in creative id ?

Comment: okay it worked by replacing  (?P<field2_id>.*) by  (?P<field2_id>[^/]+) . My field2 has : character in it.

Comment: it's usually better to be more strict, because now you'll have to make sure anything passed as `field2_id` to your view can be handled. Depends of course what are your possible field ids, but now your view will also be called with `field2_id = 498fg:592abd?output=json&name=username` for example. Now you have to check for valid field_ids in your view. If you can make your regex super-strict you don't have to worry (user gets HTTP 404 if the field_id is invalid)